# Convert datetime to epoch time with seconds in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

```
SELECT  
    CONVERT(BIGINT, DATEDIFF(ss, '1970-01-01 00:00:00', replogindatetime)) AS login,
    CONVERT(BIGINT, DATEDIFF(ss, '1970-01-01 00:00:00', replogoutdatetime)) AS logout
FROM 
    #Table
```

The `RepLoginDateTime` & `RepLogoutDateTime` are 2 columns in SQL Server `datetime` datatype, which I have to convert to epoch timestamp, but I get this error:

> Msg 535, Level 16, State 0, Line 23
>   The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff with a less precise datepart.

I'm using SQL Server 2008

Comment: You want the seconds since the epoch? Could you use minutes instead?

Comment: No point in using convert here. Datediff alweays returns int. And result of Datediff is out of int range. So you are getting this error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql server datetime to bigint (epoch) overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15634833/sql-server-datetime-to-bigint-epoch-overflow)

Comment: For millisecond, the maximum difference between startdate and enddate is 24 days, 20 hours, 31 minutes and 23.647 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

`DATEDIFF` in SQL Server returns an `int`. From SQL Server 2016 you also have `DATEDIFF_BIG`, which returns a `bigint`. This means, if you have a value that is going to be too large for an `int` you'll get an overflow error when using `DATEDIFF`.

It, however, surprises me your getting an overflow here, as `1970-01-01` plus 2,147,483,647 seconds is `2038-01-19 03:14:07`.

Anyway, instead, why not get the days, and then the seconds, and add:

```
SELECT CONVERT(BIGINT,DATEDIFF(DAY, '19700101','2038-10-12 12:30:49')) * 86400 +
       DATEDIFF(ss, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, '2038-10-12 12:30:49'),0), '2038-10-12 12:30:49')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to go around the conversion functions and use a BIGINT instead.

```
DECLARE @Epoch DATETIME = CAST(0 as DATETIME)
DECLARE @TestDate DATETIME = GETDATE()

DECLARE @DaysPast BIGINT = (SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, @Epoch,@TestDate))  

DECLARE @TimeOfDayInMilliseconds BIGINT = (SELECT  DATEDIFF(ms, 0, DATEADD(Day, 0 - DATEDIFF(Day, 0, @TestDate), @TestDate)))

SELECT (@DaysPast * 86400000) + @TimeOfDayInMilliseconds
```