# Return a datetime2 column as a unix epoch

Tags: sql-server, epoch

I have a `datetime2` column in a table that I want to convert to unix epoch time and return that value as a `varchar(4000)`. I've tried the following:

```
Select Cast(DateDiff(SECOND, '19700101', [SomeTable].[DateTime2]) as varchar(4000))
From SomeTable 
Where SomeTableId = 3
```

But I'm getting syntax errors. How would I correct this?

Comment: Remove `,` before `FROM`

Comment: Still not working

Comment: even if i cast it as a numerical value, ie bigint, i still get the syntax error

Comment: What is the the exact error? When I run your code I don't get any errors...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server datetime to bigint (epoch) overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15634833/sql-server-datetime-to-bigint-epoch-overflow)