# Get yesterday start and end datestamp and convert to Unix epoch

Tags: sql-server, datetime, stored-procedures, epoch

I have a Stored Procedure that will run within a time period (between 2-3 am), but not always at the exact same time during that period.

As part of this procedure I need to do 3 steps:

1: Get the start of yesterday's date

So if today is 13/08/2020 13:51:02 I need the query to return 12/08/2020 00:00:00 and do this dynamically

2: Get the end of yesterday's date

In the above this would return 12/08/2020 23:59:59

3: Convert both values into Unix EPOCH timestamps

I have used in the past on a similar issue (that was less time-sensitive) the below bit of Code:

```
declare @yesterday date
set @yesterday = (SELECT convert(datetime, DATEADD(day, -1 ,getdate()), 23 ))
```

The Problem here is that this gives a value that is exactly 24 hours in the past, so if the SP is run at 2:15 am - it's time stamp will be different when it's run at 2:23 am or 2:53 am.

Once I've got a method of getting the start and end date to always be correct - I'll then use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15634833/sql-server-datetime-to-bigint-epoch-overflow) solution to convert the Datetime into Epoch timestamps, unless someone who answers this question has a snazzy method of doing it all in one (for which I would be eternally grateful)

Comment: Careful! The hour between 02:00 and 03:00 local time does not occur on the day of transition from standard to daylight time. It occurs twice on the day of transition back to standard time. Weird but true.

Comment: You fall under a very common and unfortunate mis-assumption about datetime accuracy. Datetime values are accurate to approx 3ms. So 23:59:59 is not "end of day". It might be close enough but it is far better to use logic that will not fail rather than logic that "should work" if we assume much about the data. Logic for converting a datetime value to unix epoch can be easily found.

Comment: Short answer - don't use an inclusive upper boundary. Use an exclusive one that will always work regardless of the datatype involved. Eg., where x >= '20200812 00:00' and x < '20200813 00:00'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get midnight yesterday, do this:

```
DECLARE @yesterday DATETIME
    = DATEADD(DAY, -1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE));
```

To get midnight today do

```
 DECLARE @today DATETIME = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE);
```

To filter for times that happened yesterday, do

```
WHERE ts >= @yesterday AND ts < @today ...
```

The CAST operation truncates the date/time value returned by GETDATE() to midnight.

The form of WHERE with `>=` and `<` copes with the edge case correctly. It also happens to exploit an index on the column I called `ts`.

Comment: Thanks for that - although for the Midnight yesterday - you're missing a Bracket - and it took me a couple of minutes to figure out why it wasn't working :D